# Customize SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP (=False) form in Django all auth

Tags: django, django-allauth

After trying to login through the facebook account, I want to display user a form where he/she can input the username and password to store in the Django actual user model so that user can later sign in using that credentials in the system.

Thus, I am setting

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
```

in my `settings.py` file.

By default it shows a form with `username` and `e-mail address`. I want to add `password` field to the at form. How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, I did. There's a template tag called `{% if password.usable %}` or something like this (have a look at docs), if it's not usable display your custom form and do the work.